# Dart アプリのデータベースを複数の端末で同期したい

Tags: dart

現在端末ごとにsqfliteでデータを保存しています。
これを何か個人のクラウドを利用し、その個人が持っている複数の端末でデータを同期する仕組みを組み込みたいと考えています。

例えば、アプリ使用者個人のアカウントを使いGoogleDriveにTextFileを置いて、個人の端末２～３台でアクセス・同期する。
これを何らかの無料サービスを用いてクラウドデータベースで行いたい。

条件としては
・フリーで公開する予定なのでデータベースは個人のアカウントを用いて個人のクラウドサービスを用いる
つまりアプリ開発者の作成したデータベースをシェアして使うのは対象外

Firebaseデータベースで出来そうだったのですが、これはアプリ開発者が作ったデータベースをみんなで使うというもので個人個人のクラウドサービスを使うのでは無いとの認識でいますので、その認識があっているならば対象外です。

参考になるページや上記をかなえるサービスなどアドバイスいただければ幸いです。

Comment: 1つのデータベースをみんなで共有するのか、もしくは利用者個人が好きなようにクラウドに保存できるようにするのか、辺りをもう少し詳しく想定している条件等を書いておくと回答が付きやすくなると思います。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。想定条件を追記しました。